# jquery slide animations going out of sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I currently have a carousel slider which contains some text. When the user clicks the 'next' button the .carousel-text div sides up hiding the text, the carousel moves to the next slide then the .carousel-text on the next slide slides down to reveal the text.

This works fine some of the time but sometimes it will go wrong and the text will slide up and down before the carousel moves on. I'm assuming this is because the next button is clicked before the whole sequence has finished (the whole thing takes 2 seconds). Is there a way to make sure the whole thing is complete before it is called again?

```
jQuery("#arrow-right").click(function () {

    jQuery('.carousel-text').animate({  
         marginTop: "-260px"
         }, 500, function() {
            jQuery('.carousel-inner').animate({ 
                marginLeft: "-700px"
                }, 1000, function() {
                    jQuery('.carousel-text').animate({  
                        marginTop: "0px"
                        }, 500, function() {
                            // Animation complete.
                        });         
                });
    });
}
```

EDIT: Just made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UGE44/

Comment: you should make a demo of your work so far on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Place a ".stop(true, true)" before you animate.  This will stop the previous animations and allow the new ones to start all at the same time.  Would look something like this:

```
jQuery('.carousel-text').stop(true, true).animate({  
         marginTop: "-260px"
         }, 500, function() {
            jQuery('.carousel-inner').stop(true, true).animate({ 
                marginLeft: "-700px"
                }, 1000, function() {
                    jQuery('.carousel-text').stop(true, true).animate({  
                        marginTop: "0px"
                        }, 500, function() {
                            // Animation complete.
                        });         
                });
    });
```

Your may want to play around with which animates you place them before, as it may not need to be in all three spots.

Comment: Tried it on all three (http://jsfiddle.net/58NQe/) or just the first one (http://jsfiddle.net/svkjX/ )and it doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

Set "animating" flag before animate and clear it when animation is done.

```
jQuery("#arrow-right").click(function () {

    var $text = jQuery('.carousel-text');

    if ($text.data('animating') !== true) {

        $text.data('animating', true)
             .animate({  
            marginTop: "-260px"
         }, 500, function() {
            jQuery('.carousel-inner').animate({ 
                marginLeft: "-700px"
                }, 1000, function() {
                    jQuery('.carousel-text').animate({  
                        marginTop: "0px"
                        }, 500, function() {
                            $text.data('animating', false);
                            // Animation complete.
                        });         
                });
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: tried that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/daveywb/54Wtu/6/) but doesn't seem to be having any effect

Comment: That works as it only has functionality for one slide. Once you add more than one then it starts going out of sync like this http://jsfiddle.net/daveywb/54Wtu/6/